# Setting input value trough JS messes with HTML input validation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm having an issue in React where I have a credit card number field where I want to allow only numbers and I want to add a space between every 4 digits.

When I set the value with the space it breaks the HTML field validation and the field appears as valid where it must not be.

I have reproduced the same issue with plain JS:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("CardInput");

input.addEventListener("change", e => {
  const plainNumber = e.currentTarget.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

  e.currentTarget.value = plainNumber.replace(/\d{4}(?=.)/g, "$& ");
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Credit card number
    <input id="CardInput" type="text" required="" minlength="16" maxlength="23" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9 ]+" value="">
  </label>
  <button>
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Is you start typing in the form you will be able to submit the field with less than 16 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your custom validate. So you can try to make something like this

```js
    const input = document.getElementById("CardInput");

        input.addEventListener("input", e => {
          const plainNumber = e.currentTarget.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

          e.currentTarget.value = plainNumber.replace(/\d{4}(?=.)/g, "$& ");
        });
        
        input.addEventListener('change', () => {
          if (input.value.length !== 19) {
            input.setCustomValidity(`Expected 16 digits found ${input.value.length}`);
          } else {
            input.setCustomValidity("")
          }
        })
```

```css
input:invalid {
      border-color: red;
    }
```

```html
        <form>
          <label>
            Credit card number
            <input id="CardInput" type="text" required minlength="16" maxlength="19" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9 ]+" value="">
          </label>
          <button>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
```